# 'Email Quote' button issue

Tags: email, button, quote

The 'Email Quote' button which is visible on the page layout on Quote records, is greyed out. I have added the 'Allow Email' permission to all of the Quote Status Values and this has not resolved the issue. Has anyone experienced a similar issue when working with Quotes?

Comment: is your quote locked by an approval process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To enable the 'Email Reservation' button, a PDF must be created (by clicking 'Create PDF' and saving the record. Once the new pdf record has been added to the 'Quote PDF's' related list, then the 'Email Reservation' button will become active.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the deliverability settings as shown below

[image]